# Python: How can I detect keyboard input in a non-blocking manner without external libraries? (I.e. without "keyboard" package)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Just as the title states, I'm trying to detect when the user presses a key in python (specifically the arrow keys) in a non-blocking manner without importing any external packages.

For context, this is for an assignment which uses tkinter. We are expressly forbidden from using the "keyboard" package or any other external packages in the assignment.

Comment: Then shouldn't your course have covered how to do this?

Comment: Maybe the course told to ask stackoverflow

Comment: Unfortunately, the course has nothing to do with input handling. The professor is just a stubborn guy haha. He just kinda told us "It's possible. Figure it out."

Answer (score 1):

```
# make a function that will be called when a key is pressed
def on_key_press(event):
    # check if the pressed key is the 'Up' arrow key
    if event.keysym == 'Up':
        # do whatever needs to be done when that key is pressed
        print("Hurray, up!")

# create an instance of Tk, which is the main window of the application in tkinter
root = tk.Tk()

# bind the key press event to the 'on_key_press' function for the main window
root.bind("<KeyPress>", on_key_press)

# to enter the main loop and keep the window open, waiting for events
root.mainloop()
```